# android (apache harmony) garbage collection

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, dalvik

The Sun JDK has a `java.lang.ref.Finalizer` class, which is used during garbage collection. In Apache Harmony, the standard library that Android is based on, does not have the class.

My question is: what is the dalvik/harmony equivalent of `java.lang.ref.Finalizer`? And what source code of dalvik can I look at to understand the garbage collection aspect of VM design?

Comment: The java.lang.ref.Finalizer class you mention isn't a public API in either platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the Android source code by following the instructions [on the Android devleopers website](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html). This should (to my knowledge) include the Dalvik VM.

You simply need to define the `finalize()` method to add a finalizer to a class.

Comment: I want to know the VM mechanism to implement the finalizer semantics.